# How to get the page_ids from a list of page_slugs from WordPress and store them as a string?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

What I want to do is create a wordpress function to get the page_ids from a list of page_slugs and store them as a string in a variable which I can then simply "echo" / "call" from inside another function.

So far, I can get a single page_id from a page_slug with this:

```
$the_page_slug = 'test';
global $wpdb;
$page_id_from_slug = '\'' . $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name ='".$the_page_slug."'") . '\'';

echo $page_id_from_slug;

result is ok: '12'
```

and this function works too

```
function id_from_slug($the_page_slug){
global $wpdb;
$page_id_from_slug = '\'' . $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name ='".$the_page_slug."'") . '\'';
return $page_id_from_slug;
}
echo id_from_slug('test');

result is ok: '12'
```

The problem is that I cant get it to work with an array of page_slugs.

My Data is like this:

```
$the_page_slugs = array('test', 'test-nr4', 'test-9', 'sample4', 'sample-nr12');
```

the echo output (page_ids) should come out like this:

'12', '16', '54', '76', '123'

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the below.

```
global $wpdb;

$the_page_slugs = array('test', 'test-nr4', 'test-9', 'sample4', 'sample-nr12');
$page_id_from_slug = '\'' . $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name in '" . implode("','",$the_page_slugs) . "'") . '\'';

echo $page_id_from_slug;
```

Comment: thanks, was a great starting point. Main prob was that get_var only brings back ONE result. an by the way you missed the IN brackets ;)

Answer (score 1):

So here is my solution, works fine, just how I need it.
Look at the code and see what I changed/added:

The IN() and IMPLODE() hint was really what I needed and after changing "get_vars" (only gets ONE result) to "get_results" and a bit tweaking it worked.

Here is my code, for sure it can be improved...

```
        // code to get page_ids from page_slugs
        // the list of page_slugs
$the_page_slugs = array('test', 'test-re', '1234', 'test-56', 'sample34', 'me3-uc', '1-12987-db', 'thy-m2o-1873');
        // set global, just in case ;)
global $wpdb;
        // query to get the page_ids
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN('" . implode("', '", $the_page_slugs) . "') AND post_status = 'publish'";
        //this calls the query
$get_page_ids = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql));
        //prepare new var
$the_page_ids ='';
        //loop thru results to create var
foreach($get_page_ids as $get_page_ids_result){
        //formate results, need it comma separated
    $the_page_ids .= ('' == $the_page_ids ) ? '':', ';
        //fill it
    $the_page_ids .= $get_page_ids_result->ID;
    }
echo "check if result is what we need<br/>";
echo $the_page_ids;
        //perfekt result, looks like: 325, 323, 324, 327, 328, 329, 334, 335
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

change your sql to :

```
"SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name in (".implode(",",$the_page_slugs)."))";
```

it will have array of records on success to `print_r` after getting from database.

Comment: not bad, didnt really work for me but gave me a "hint" to what I was missing. Thanks